# HuggingFace - BERT NLP Model - OSError - (Error)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

When running the BERT NLP Model of HuggingFace, it ouputs the OSError below. Below is the code and Error,

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

## Instantiate Model
# the nlp bert pre-trained model used here is from website huggingface. the website is " https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment "

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment')  
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment')


## Encode and Calculate Sentiment ( Now entering string words to test the sentiment score )

tokens = tokenizer.encode('I hated this, absolutely the worst', return_tensors='pt' )
result = model(tokens)

print(result)
```

Error Below,

> OSError: Can't load the model for
> 'nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment'. If you were trying
> to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't
> have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure
> 'nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment' is the correct path
> to a directory containing a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5,
> model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack.

Comment: Have you read the error message and tried its suggestions? i.e. make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name, and make sure 'nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack.

Comment: Yes i have read it. For the same name local directory part, the only similar things i can think of is that i have a Folder with all my Python Files that were under the 32 bit and version 3.7, before i upgraded to 64 bit, under a Folder Name called "Python37-32". After i upgraded to 64 Bit and to version 3.8, I have a second Folder called "Python38". I copied all my python files and also put them in folder "Python38". I thought maybe since both folders share the same word "Python", that might be the problem. so i changed one of the folders name, but i still get same error.

Comment: Also, this source code file above is named "Sentiment Analysis - BERT Model". I do have another source code file named "Sentiment Analysis - TextBlob". I thought maybe since they share the same words "Sentiment Analysis", that could be the problem. But when i took of the "Sentiment Analysis" of the BERT Model File, i still get the same Error.

Comment: In terms of the correct path for the NLP Model link " nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment", i followed the instructions of the excercise, all the exact words for the coding and correct imports of modules there. For these files "pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack", where would i find them ? i downloaded the latest PyTorch , if your pointing if there inside PyTorch, wouldn't they automatically be inside PyTorch ?

Comment: @kwsp, i responded to your statement. What are your thoughts ?

Comment: When you say you moved the python folders, do you mean folder with your own source code, or the Python's own folders (i.e. the one that contains `site-packages`, `includes` etc.)?

Comment: I didnt move any Folders. I coppied the Source Code Files that was in the "Python 37-32" Folder, and pasted them inside "Python38" folder. When i upgraded to Python Version 3.8, it automatically created a Folder called "Python38". What i mean is the Source Code files, the actual Code of the Different Programs i save. Both Bolders have the Source Files. I copied the Source Code files from Folder "Python37-32" and also pasted it into "Python38"

Comment: Going forward i was planning to write only new source code files in "Python38", and the other folder "Python37-32" was just a back up copy of the previous source code files (programs) that i created with Python 3.7 before i did the upgrade to 3.8.  in terms of site packages, before i upgraded i did a "Pip Freeze" so all of them transferred/installed into Python 3.8 successfully.